# How to list all fonts in my project directory

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, resourcedictionary

iam using a app for drawing purpose i have a font collection to be used in it. I added a folder in my project name "Fonts" and place all font files inside it. Now i need to list and use all those fonts in it. How to do so?? This is the snap of it

[image: Here is view of my project fonts folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Fonts.GetFontFamilies Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms523378(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
 var fnts = Fonts.GetFontFamilies("Fonts");
```

where`"Fonts"` is the relative folder contains all your fonts

Comment: mybe it sound silly but iam unable to point to my Fonts folder can u please tell me how to that.. fonts build action is resource

Comment: you should  move your  folder within the yourApp.exe execution path  which means under bin/debug for the moment of dev and after in the installation path